# Where has my text gone?

Tags: css, z-index

On my [site](http://sebastiansalek.com/depfinder/), I was expecting to find the text in the snippet below, centered, on top of the image of the musicians.

```
<div class="brand">
    <h1>Looking for a musician at short notice?</h1>
    <div class="line-spacer"></div>
    <p><span>We can help</span></p>
</div>
```

It's currently not displaying. I think it's a z-index issue, but I'm not sure of the solution.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Relevant CSS:

```
#intro .brand
{
    margin-top: 40px;
}


.line-spacer
{
    width: 20%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 36px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6
{
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the CSS?  Or at least `.brand`, `.line-spacer` and anything for div, h1, p or span?

Comment: It's sitting under `section id="services"`

Comment: @Paulie_D correct, I just took Marcelo's suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow from #intro

```
#intro {
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You've made it appear, now to get it in the right place! Any idea why it's in the next section of my site?

Answer (score 0):

you have issue with both positioning and z-index

[image]

As of now it is position below the artists image and not above it, and since it is behind layers of other displays no text can be seen!

Try reducing the `top-margin` and adding `z-index:1`